# How to highlight a UIButton subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of `UIButton` where I overwrite `drawRect` for a custom looking button.

But now the cell doesn't highlight.

How can I fix this?

I have the code ready for another custom drawRect for when the cell is pressed.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* red = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];
    CGFloat redRGBA[4];
    [red getRed: &redRGBA[0] green: &redRGBA[1] blue: &redRGBA[2] alpha: &redRGBA[3]];

    UIColor* darkRed = [UIColor colorWithRed: (redRGBA[0] * 0.8) green: (redRGBA[1] * 0.8) blue: (redRGBA[2] * 0.8) alpha: (redRGBA[3] * 0.8 + 0.2)];
    UIColor* lightRed = [UIColor colorWithRed: (redRGBA[0] * 0.8 + 0.2) green: (redRGBA[1] * 0.8 + 0.2) blue: (redRGBA[2] * 0.8 + 0.2) alpha: (redRGBA[3] * 0.8 + 0.2)];

    //// Gradient Declarations
    NSArray* redGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                  (id)darkRed.CGColor, 
                                  (id)lightRed.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat redGradientLocations[] = {0, 1};
    CGGradientRef redGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)redGradientColors, redGradientLocations);

    //// Shadow Declarations
    CGColorRef shadow = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -0);
    CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 1;
    CGColorRef shadow2 = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    CGSize shadow2Offset = CGSizeMake(0, -0);
    CGFloat shadow2BlurRadius = 2;


    //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
    UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(35, 5, 250, 50) cornerRadius: 6];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow2Offset, shadow2BlurRadius, shadow2);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, shadow2);
    [roundedRectanglePath fill];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, redGradient, CGPointMake(160, 55), CGPointMake(160, 5), 0);

    ////// Rounded Rectangle Inner Shadow
    CGRect roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset([roundedRectanglePath bounds], -shadowBlurRadius, -shadowBlurRadius);
    roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectOffset(roundedRectangleBorderRect, -shadowOffset.width, -shadowOffset.height);
    roundedRectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(roundedRectangleBorderRect, [roundedRectanglePath bounds]), -1, -1);

    UIBezierPath* roundedRectangleNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: roundedRectangleBorderRect];
    [roundedRectangleNegativePath appendPath: roundedRectanglePath];
    roundedRectangleNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    {
        CGFloat xOffset = shadowOffset.width + round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width);
        CGFloat yOffset = shadowOffset.height;
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
                                    CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
                                    shadowBlurRadius,
                                    shadow);

        [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(roundedRectangleBorderRect.size.width), 0);
        [roundedRectangleNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
        [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
        [roundedRectangleNegativePath fill];
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];

    //// Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(redGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subclassing UIButton does not make sense because it's a kind of assembly/cluster class.

I had best experience creating own buttons when subclassing UIControl and add some custom behavior.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045672/create-uibutton-subclass) (you should not subclass UIButton).

Then also [check how you highlight UIControl subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428437/highlighting-a-uicontrol-subclass).

Comment: Oh ok.  So how do I encorporate the code I posted without making a subclass?

Comment: Why not placing the drawRect in a UIControl subclass. Then add a custom control event like this: `[self addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`;

Comment: Can you please expand on this?  Right now i just have an empty UIControl subclas with just the drawRect method I posted above.

Comment: Did you call initWithFrame with a appropriate frame when creating your Class (UIControl subclass)? After you see you drawRect drawings, then you might read on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428437/highlighting-a-uicontrol-subclass

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045672/create-uibutton-subclass#comment7668681_5045778

Comment: You can subclass UIButton. It is a concrete class, not a class cluster. I've subclassed UIButton. Apple has an example talking about subclassing UIButton.

Comment: @FeloneousCat your right. Subclassing `UIButton` makes perfect sense, under certain circumstances. One might be you wanting custom views in a `IB_Designable` button.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can deal with the highlight problem with these methods below

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

you can change the color or the image in these method