# Highlight controls programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have many controls like, image views, labels (UIControls), which have I wish to show like a dual mode controls. i.e. Based on my data, I have to set them either with image 1 or image 2 (for a image view), similarly with the label. I tried accomplishing this using the highlighted state properties of image view and labels. For the image view, I gave one image reference for highlighted and another for normal.

however when I programmatically set the highlighted property to yes, they are not toggling between them. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What code you tried yet?

Comment: I believe the OP already said: `I programmatically set the highlighted property to yes` which is not the good way to go, btw.

Comment: Are this control set above each other? Can you show the screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a
>   touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up
>   event. You can retrieve and set this value through the highlighted
>   property.

So, you don't set the `highlighted` property. Try setSelected.

Have you seen this related topic: [Highlighting a UIControl subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428437/highlighting-a-uicontrol-subclass)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected` state instead. I think `highlighted` state is a transient state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

if([imgeview isselected]){

[imageview setselected:NO];

}else{

[imageview setselected:YES];

}